# ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL during query

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2013

I have a remote MySQL database, and my deployed application (a few java microservice applications) consistently encounters the error  `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL during query` with some SQL queries. Then I tried to connect to mysql with MySQL command line client, executed the same query, and I managed to replicate the same error. Below is Mysql setup after following this page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html

```
+------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                | Value    |
+------------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout              | 3600     |
| delayed_insert_timeout       | 300      |
| have_statement_timeout       | YES      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout  | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout     | 5        |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout   | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout          | 7200     |
| lock_wait_timeout            | 50       |
| net_read_timeout             | 3000     |
| net_write_timeout            | 6000     |
| rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout | 10000    |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout       | 31536000 |
| slave_net_timeout            | 4        |
| wait_timeout                 | 7200     |
+------------------------------+----------+

+--------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name            | Value      |
+--------------------------+------------+
| max_allowed_packet       | 1073741824 |
| slave_max_allowed_packet | 1073741824 |
+--------------------------+------------+
```

However, I systematically have the same error after roughly 10 minutes after executing a big SQL query from the mysql command line client.

**Note**: On the DB server side, I notice the log [Note] Aborted connection xxxxx to db: 'xxxxx' user 'xxxxx' host 'xxxxx' (Got an error writing communication packets)

**DBA executed the query successfully on the server on which mysql is installed. But we have to use mysql remotely as a service.**

I will be grateful if anybody can help.

Comment: The error may happen if the MySQL Server process drops the connection. Since it is reproducible, I would look for evidence that the MySQL Server is crashing and restarting. Look in the mysqld error log on the server. Also check `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime'` to see if the number of seconds since the last restart correlates with the time you got the aborted connection error (or a short time later, since it had to restart and do crash recovery).

Comment: You don't show the SQL query that caused this error, but since it ran for at least 10 minutes when you got the error, I suppose it is complex. It might be creating excessive load on the server, running out of space in RAM or disk, etc.

Comment: @BillKarwin I just checked the uptime variable, and confirm that mysql db didn't restart since I got it up last time (about 2 days ago). The query is very long and nasty. It cannot be easily understood without the business domain knowledge. The weird thing is that the issue is systematically reproducible. I just reproduced it again 10 mins ago.

Comment: I would try to redesign the query to be less complex and nasty. Obviously it is too much in its current form. You may not be able to do it all in a single query, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the root cause was a network issue. Our remote MySQL instance is exposed as service. There's an additional proxy between the client and MySQL DB. By default, the connection will be closed if no communication between client and server over 10 mins.

Comment: Hello, i might have the same issue. How do i found out if there is a proxy between them?